# Changing view's alpha based on UIScrollView's contentOffset.x when scrolling multiple screens

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, contentoffset

I have a horizontal `UIScrollView` that has a width of `960`.

The `UIScrollView` contains 3 `UIView's`, each one set to a background color.

The first one is pink, the second blue, and the third is green.

What I need to do is change the alpha of the colors(views) based on the user scrolling.

So if the user is on the first screen (pink) and starts to scroll to the second page (blue), then the pink should start to fade and the blue will become more visible, and once the user fully swipes to that 2nd page it would be all blue.

Here is how I do this when using only one `UIView`:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        // Offset Percentage
        var percentageHorizontalOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x / 320;

        // Reduce alpha
        pinkView.alpha = percentageHorizontalOffset
}
```

This is easy because the percentage goes from `0.0` to `1.0`

However, I need to modify the code to support 3 screens. I tried this earlier by replacing `320` with `960` in the method above but this causes a couple problems.

The first is that you are no longer getting a percentage in the range of 0.0 to 1.0, once you scroll on the second page it will be a range of 1.0 to 2.0 which won't help me properly modify the alpha.

The second is that the alpha change doesn't feel very smooth, especially when the UIScrollView is swiped quickly. I setup a mess of `if` statements earlier trying to get this to work but nothing worked.

How can I properly fade the alpha of all 3 `UIView's` based on the `contentOffset.x` when my `UIScrollView's` content size is bigger than just one screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way would be to treat the 3 colored views as an array.

```
// Put all your views in an array
@property NSArray *coloredViews;

// Later where you set things up, allocate the array.
coloredViews=@[pinkView,blueView,greenView];
```

Then use the following algorithm to set the alpha.
This assumes only 2 of N views on screen at a time. One on left and one on the right.
The alpha of the left is based on the amount of it off screen. 
The alpha of the right is based on the amount of it on screen.
So as left goes off it goes to 0 causing right to go to 1 and vice versa.

This makes your scroll method:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
  // Work out which view is showing on the left. 0 to N-1
  // Based on each being 320 wide.
  CGFloat offset=scrollView.contentOffset.x;
  NSUInteger leftHandSideViewIndex=(NSUInteger)offset.x/320;

  // Left hand side alpha is 1 minus percentage (as a fraction) off screen
  self.coloredViews[leftHandSide].alpha = 
    1.0 - (offset - (320.0 * leftHandSideViewIndex))/320.0;

  // Right hand side alpha is 1 - percentage (as a fraction) on screen
  // Only do this if there is a right hand side.
  if (leftHandSideViewIndex < self.coloredViews.count-1){
    self.coloredViews[leftHandSide+1].alpha = 
      1.0 - ((320.0 * leftHandSizeViewIndex+1)-offset)/320.0;
  }
}
```

Give it a try. Might not be 100% right, but hopefully gives you the idea.You probably want to set a width variable rather than using 320.0.